# How to turn book club raw data into organised table please?

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, transpose

Long story short, I’ve recently joined a charity library / book club. Owners are old but they are sweetest; they have an old computer system to keep tracks of rented books but no one really tried to take the extra step by analysing data (who took what, when; which book’s still available; how many overdues; etc…).

I’m no expert in data analysis, but I dabble with Excel / Google Sheets.
The computer export data this way : https://i.ibb.co/ynkWD2C/bookstore-actual.png

And ideally, I would like to transpose everything into this: https://i.ibb.co/fp4y45Z/bookstore-ideal.png

The goal is for instance to find who took / who is holding a particular book; how many copies of books do we have in stock etc…

Any help welcome, I just want to give the guys some hand.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: I'm almost speechless, thank you guys for your contributions! I'll review them tomorrow and revert, but they look really nice.**

Comment: This is going to take code and code in Excel is very different than code in google sheets.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a few stages.
First you extract dates and rent ID's, then you find lists.
My solution is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mfoo_gbRsVBQ_74gjYGdwmxDY87ngYNWpCJXrEwgqos/copy

It's not perfect as it contains one hidden column where I keep my partial results.
Also it's limited to records of maximum 50 000 characters as it uses join function to merge whole column into one cell for processing (as far as I know join formula has a limit of 50 000 characters).

Comment: Good answer.  I hadn't improved my query for dates and rent IDs the way you have, using REGEXTRACT...

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, though I'm sure there are more elegant solutions.  And it assumes that your data is consistent.
Look at my sample sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1diBJ7PGX-Ja4suvS7j6ZrK1xwBY5Ssk1DWxjcXNGzas/edit?usp=sharing

The key formula is:

```
=iferror(
if(len(B3)>0,
   transpose(query({indirect("A"&index(match(B2,A$1:A,0)+4) & ":" &
                             "A"&index(match(B3,A$1:A,0)-3))},
                  "select *")),
   transpose(query({indirect("A"&index(match(B2,A$1:A,0)+4) & ":" &
                             "A"&ArrayFormula(max(if(A$1:A="#LIST#",row(A1:A)))-1))}))),
"")
```

If this seems workable for you, I can add some more detailed explanation.  But it basically creates a list of all of your "Rent" IDS, a matching list of rental dates, and then a query that looks up each Rent ID, and lists all of the books before the next Rent ID.

It has to do a special match for the last entry in the data list, since then it doesn't have a following Rent ID to look for.
Let us know if this helps.

**Update:**
Note that Krzysztof's answer more precisely captures the first two columns, since he uses a more complete filter, checking for digits in the right places.  I only looked for rows beginning with "Rent ", which could potentially match a book title.  My dates should be okay, assuming no book starts with "Date: ".

But otherwise, for the columns of book titles, you can use either of our two formulas, whichever approach you prefer.